# "../" doesn't seem to work in specifying ProcessInfo filenames

Tags: c#, process

I run into an issue when specifying the parent directories in Process StartInfo filenames where the filepath is unable to be found.

Want something like this to work:

```py
p.StartInfo.FileName = "../../../example/env/Scripts/python.exe"
```

This works, but I don't want to reset the working directory since any output from the python script gets redirected:

```py
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "../../../example/env/Scripts/"
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe"
```

Is there an alternative that allows me to specify the filename path with parent directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8) to convert the relative path to an absolute path, and then [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) to put the two pieces together:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(
                           Path.GetFullPath("../../../example/env/Scripts"),
                           "python.exe")
                       );
```